# Battery icon with problem with some themes

Tags: themes, icons, elementary

I'm using the elementary icon theme from their PPA, it's great, but have some problems. In almost all cases I fix it without any problem, but I can't solve this one.

The battery icon is "missing" and it show and ugly battery icon, I don't have sure from where it came and how to change it. Does anyone have any information that can help me to fix it?

I already tried to change the name of the file, copy from other themes, make inherent themes too, and nothing solve it.

Ps.: Already "Googled" it, but just found some people with problems like "missing icon" or something like that.

Comment: Here is an image of the problem:
http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg825/scaled.php?server=825&filename=batteryicondamn.png&res=medium

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing Faenza icon set. The problems were the `~/icons/Faenza/status/scalable/battery****symbolic.svg symlinks`. They were pointing at some ugly big squarish battery drawings. I replaced them with those in the `usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/24/`

Just copied all the battery `*.*` files to `~/icons/Faenza/status/scalable/` overwriting everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug(s). Currently the elementary-icon-theme (at least the daily's, which I assume you are using) borrows from gnomes default icon theme for some icons which have yet to be designed for a future release of elementary-icon-theme (previewed in the daily PPA). There also some sort of upstream scaling bug affecting the indicator-power and the designer(s) are awaiting a fix for that before designing/implementing a new icon for indicator-power.

Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryicons/+bug/845037 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryicons/+bug/910616 and click 'also affects' if it pleases you. Although the designers/developers are already fully aware of both bugs.